# More than one Google account

Tags: gmail, google-account

Does Google allow someone to have more than one personal Google account?

If not, is there any way to have more than one Gmail in an account?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple Google Accounts. I have three myself (not counting a Google Apps account from my employer, not to mention a couple of email addresses I've reserved for my kids). What do you mean by "have more than one gmail in an account"? A Google Account = a Gmail account. You get one Gmail address with your Google Account. That said, there are ways to manage several Gmail addresses through one Gmail mailbox. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you concern legal issues, I did not notice anything against it in its [Terms of Use](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/).  btw, There's not any term allowing it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

From George Wright [here](http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/159598-gmail-account-limit.html):

> I have over 30. Never a problem. I use my real name and only one "alternate" email for all of them, (which is a gmail account too) and have never had a problem. I don't think they have a limit.

Edit. The above was based on the [gmail] tag to the Q. If Google Account was indeed the subject the answer is still that more than one account is permitted (see [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180802?hl=en) for implied though not specified permission).